# Failing test case on timezones on Kattis

Tags: python, timezone

I am trying to solve a problem titled Time Zones on Kattis in Python 3. The link to the problem is [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/timezones)
My current solution:

```
zones = {
"UTC": 0,
"GMT": 0,
"BST": 1,
"IST": 1,
"WET": 0,
"WEST": 1,
"CET": 1,
"CEST": 2,
"EET": 2,
"EEST": 3,
"MSK": 3,
"MSD": 4,
"AST": -4,
"ADT": -3,
"NST": -3.5,
"NDT": -2.5,
"EST": -5,
"EDT": -4,
"CST": -6,
"CDT": -5,
"MST": -7,
"MDT": -6,
"PST": -8,
"PDT": -7,
"HST": -10,
"AKST": -9,
"AKDT": -8,
"AEST": 10,
"AEDT": 11,
"ACST": 9.5,
"ACDT": 10.5,
"AWST": 8,
}


def add_hours_to_time(input_time, hours_to_add):
    # Split the time string into hours, minutes, and am/pm/noon/midnight parts
    time_parts = input_time.split()
    # Handle "noon" and "midnight" cases
    if len(time_parts) == 1:
        if time_parts[0] == "noon":
            hours = 12
            minutes = 0
        elif time_parts[0] == "midnight":
            hours = 0
            minutes = 0
    else:
        time = time_parts[0]
        period = time_parts[1]
        hours, minutes = tuple(map(int, time.split(':')))
        # Convert to 24-hour format
        if period == 'p.m.':
            if hours != 12:
                hours += 12
        elif period == 'a.m.':
            if hours == 12:
                hours = 0
    # Calculate new hours and minutes
    new_hours = hours + hours_to_add
    new_hours = new_hours % 24
    new_minutes = minutes
    # Decimal handling
    if str(new_hours).endswith(".5"):
        new_minutes += 30
        if new_minutes >= 60:
            new_hours += 1
            over_minutes = new_minutes % 60
            new_minutes = over_minutes
    new_hours = int(new_hours)
    # Final output
    if new_hours == 12:
        if new_minutes == 0:
            time_str = "noon"
        else:
            time_str = f"{new_hours}:{new_minutes:02d} p.m."
    elif new_hours == 0:
        if new_minutes == 0:
            time_str = "midnight"
        else:
            time_str = f"{new_hours + 12}:{new_minutes:02d} a.m."
    else:
        if new_hours < 12:
            time_str = f"{new_hours}:{new_minutes:02d} a.m."
        else:
            new_hours -= 12
            if new_hours == 0:
                time_str = f"{new_hours + 12}:{new_minutes:02d} p.m."
            else:
                time_str = f"{new_hours}:{new_minutes:02d} p.m."
    return time_str


n = int(input())
results = []
for i in range(n):
    times = input()
    times = times.split()
    if len(times) == 4:
        area1 = times[2]
        area2 = times[3]
        diff = zones[area2] - zones[area1]
        result = add_hours_to_time(f"{times[0]} {times[1]}", diff)
        results.append(result)
    elif len(times) == 3:
        area1 = times[1]
        area2 = times[2]
        diff = zones[area2] - zones[area1]
        result = add_hours_to_time(times[0], diff)
        results.append(result)
for something in results:
    print(something)
```

My code always fails the second test case (1/2 test cases solved). When I first submitted it, I failed the second test case. That was when I realised I should have included decimal support, since there were timezones with half-hour differences. I incorporated decimal support (shown by the decimal handling comment), submitted it again, and it still failed the second one.
My code seems perfectly fine to me and I tried numerous of my own test cases, all of which were successful.
I tried decimal test cases, negative test cases, negative decimal test cases, and more.
None of them are incorrect.
My current strategy is to intentionally try to get an incorrect test case, and debug it to pinpoint the issue.
I expect that my code would be perfectly fine and would successfully solve the problem, however, I am still stuck with the last hidden test case.
I have tried using ChatGPT. I have tried identifying corner cases. Nothing is working. I am still stuck with the last hidden test case.

Comment: I looked at the Kattis link and its list of time zones. I see that your list mimics their sample list. In scanning their sample, there appears to be a lot of missing time zone codes (e.g. for Russian time zones). Perhaps, their list was meant to be a starter, but they actually want all of the codes included. You might check out the link to the time and date website "timeanddate.com/time/zones".

Comment: The Kattis problem may be a fun exercise, but it is very wrong with regard to how time zones work, and how you should use them in python.  In particular, it says _"Time zones have recently been given standard capital-letter abbreviations..."_, which is false. There are no standards for time zone abbreviations.  Nor can time zones be mapped uniquely from abbreviation to offset, nor is their list complete in any way. To do time zones correctly in Python, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), which implements [the TZ database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your decimal timezone handling, the hours could be greather then 23 but your code does not wrap in that case. for example when converting `8:50 a.m. MDT ACST`. the result is 20 minutes past midnight, but your code counts it as 20 minutes past 24. in which case your code will print `12:20 p.m.` instead of the correct `12:20 a.m.`

Comment: Yeah, I get that incorrect test case now. So how can my code handle this case and fix it?

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Does anybody know how to close this question? There's a good answer on this so I don't want to delete it entirely

Comment: @OwJi If an "answer" answers your question there is a check mark next to that question that you can click to mark the answer as the "accepted" answer. That closes the question in the manner your looking for.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've done that now